# Smart tabs in vim

Tags: vim

Is there any way to make vim handle `tab` pressing by the next two ways?

1. Insert usual tab for indent.
2. Insert spaces for alignment.

Result of usage should looks as follows (`--->` it's tabs, `_` it's spaces)

```
foo() {
--->int_a_____=_2;
--->int_count_=_12;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, I don't know a configuration option, but you can use [tabular.vim](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) to handle the alignment...  http://vimcasts.org/episodes/aligning-text-with-tabular-vim/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is the [Smart Tabs plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=231). I don't use it, but it looks like it does what you want.

*Edit*: Actually, I have written my own implementation of this, because I wanted some additional features (like still use Tabs after a comment prefix), and needed it to integrate with my own variant of the *SuperTab* plugin, which also overrides the  key. I've just uploaded my [IndentTab plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4243), so that you have a choice.

Comment: Hey @Ingo, thanks for this. However, the "ingo" library is a bad idea: it's ok for you, who are Ingo, and use it for everything, but for other people it's only an extra dependency and introduce unneeded coupling just to save a little bit of code (at least in this plugin). I'll be using your 1.00 version. Please consider removing the dependency and thank you again ;)

Comment: @piro: Thanks for the feedback; though I politely disagree. With over 100 published plugins, there would be huge duplication or incompatibilities without that library. You're right that this plugin (so far) only uses a fraction, but all that effort to duplicate and copy around functions would prevent me from working on the plugins themselves. I hope you'll accept 363 kB of dependency for all the benefits the plugin provides.